# What is a "recognition network" in ML?

Tags: neural-networks, inference

The authors of ["Composing graphical models with neural networks
for structured representations and fast inference"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06277.pdf) consistently refer to "recognition networks", for example:

> The variational autoencoder (VAE) handles general non-conjugate observation models by introducing recognition networks.

I assume a recognition network is a type of neural network, but when I google the term, I don't find an authoritative source on what a "recognition network" actually is in machine learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a well established term.

In the context of the paper, "recognition" seems to be the task of determining a probability distribution over the latent variables in the model. For example, in VAE, the encoder of the network is trained to model $p(z|X)$ by directly estimating the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The encoder is what the paper calls the recognition network.

> We learn recognition networks that output conjugate graphical model potentials instead of outputting the complete variational distribution’s parameters directly. These potentials are then used in graphical model inference algorithms in place of the non-conjugate observation likelihoods.

The authors seem to propose recognition networks which model $p(z|X)$ in a more indirect manner rather than simply predicting the parameters directly.